# Wrong alignment for floats array

Tags: c++, vulkan

Im passing uniform buffer to compute shader in vulkan. The buffer contains an array of 49 floating point numbers (gaussian matrix). Everything is fine, but when I read array in the shader, it gives only 13 values, the others are 0 or gunk, and they correspond to 0, 4, 8, etc. of initial array. I think its some kind of alignment problem
Shader layouts are

```
struct Pixel
{
 vec4 value;
};

layout(push_constant) uniform params_t
{
 int width;
 int height;

} params;

layout(std140, binding = 0) buffer buf
{
  Pixel imageData[];
};

layout (binding = 1) uniform sampler2D inputTex;

layout (binding = 2) uniform unf_t
{
 float gauss[SAMPLE_SIZE*SAMPLE_SIZE];
};
```

Could that be binding 0 influencing binding 2? and if so how can I copy array to buffer with needed alignment? Currently I use

```
vkCmdUpdateBuffer(a_cmdBuff, a_uniform, 0, a_gaussSize, (const uint32_t *)gauss)
```

or may be better to split on different sets?

Edit: by expanding buffer and array i manage to pass it with alignment of 16 and all great, but it looks like a waste of memory. How can I align floats by 4?

Comment: How did you set up the uniform buffer in C++ and how do you fill/update it?

Comment: As I sad I update it with `vkCmdUpdateBuffer`. But what do you mean by set up? Creation? Binding? Memory allocation? Everything?

Comment: You said "by expanding buffer and array i manage to pass it with alignment of 16". Where did you change that? How would your change affect the alignment of floats?

Comment: size of array was 49 and became 4 * 49 where every 0,4,8 etc is matrix element

Comment: "size of array" where? in your shader? in the C++ code that constructs or fills the buffer? Did you accidentally allocate only 49 *bytes* instead of 49 *floats*? Withholding information will not allow us to help you.

Comment: in C++ code where i fiil buffer `float gauss[SAMPLE_SIZE * SAMPLE_SIZE * 4];` *4 makes array larger than it should be. Then I fill it `gauss[(SAMPLE_EDGE + x + SAMPLE_SIZE * (SAMPLE_EDGE + y))*4] = (*math*) ` and pass to vkCmdUpdateBuffer. As you see i fill only 0, 4, 8 etc

Comment: From further reading, it seems that uniform buffers in Vulkan are required to use `std140` packing, which means every element of a `float[]` must be aligned to the size of a vec4, or 16 bytes. The more efficient std430 packing is explicitly disallowed for uniform blocks. This is the exact problem you are facing. See also [this answer](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/a/8700).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uniform blocks require that array elements are aligned to vec4 (16 bytes).

To work around this you use a vec4 instead and you can pass 52 floats and then take the correct component based on `index/4` and `index%4`.